# How to Make an Alert Box in HTML With Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, html, newline, alert

Does anyone know how to make an alert box in HTML that has multiple lines? I looking for the output to be something like this:

```
Rules:
1. Blah Blah Blah
2. Blah Blah Blah
3. Blah Blah Blah
[Cancel]   [Ok]
```

Here is the code so far in javascript:

```js
function rules() {
  agree = confirm("RULES: 1. Blah Blah Blah<br> 2. Blah Blah Blah<br> 3. Blah Blah Blah<br> Press OK to agree and Cancel to Dissagree")
  if (agree == true) {
    alert("Thank you for agreeing to the rules!")
  } else {
    alert("You can not move on unless you agree to the rules.")
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="rules()">Agree to the Rules</button>
```

I tried using `<br>`, but those don't seem to format in alert boxes. The output I get is this:
[image: alert box on 1 line]
Does anyone know how I can add another line into an alert box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inserting \n creates a new Line

```js
function rules() {
  agree = confirm("RULES: 1. Bl\nah Blah Blah 2. Bla\nh Blah Blah 3. Bla\nh Blah Blah Press OK to agree and Cancel to Dissagree")
  if (agree == true) {
    alert("Thank you for agreeing to the rules!")
  } else {
    alert("You can not move on unless you agree to the rules.")
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="rules()">Agree to the Rules</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

alert("This is first Line \nThis is second line \nThis is third Line");

Comment: Consider formatting your answer as a snippet, and including an explanation as to why the code works?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `'\n'` for creating lines.

For example, your rules string would be:

```
'Rules:\n1. Blah Blah Blah\n2. Blah Blah Blah\n3. Blah Blah Blah'
```